# how to render react datepicker properly without using npm?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker, react-dates, react-datetime

here is my code, I can't use npm

```
<DatePicker className="form-control" Delected={this.state.startDate}                            
onChange={this.handleChange}name="startDate"                          
dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"/>

<script src="~/scripts/react.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/react-date-picker.js"></script>
```

[This is how it looks when we render it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Zs4.png)

i have tried many css files,cdn's everything please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are missing the default styling sheet titled "react-datetime.css" which can be found at the [GitHub repository for react-datetime by user YouCanBookMe](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/tree/master/css).

Comment: Thanks, Avi I really appreciate it